# Find Main Class of referenced jar

Tags: java, class, jar, javafx, program-entry-point

A JavaFX application (jar) is referenced as an dependency in my project.

The "Main Class" in this jar contains the main method and the start method, to run this application.

Now i want to find this "Main Class" from another class, so that i can start the application without passing the exactly name of the "Main Class". Is there any possible solution to find the class name in a referenced jar?

Comment: Can you make the JavaFX jar file an executable jar file?

Comment: It is already an executable jar, thats not the point.

Answer (score 1):

The first element[by first i mean first element which entered the stack] in current thread stacktrace is main class. Try this:

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread ().getStackTrace ();
StackTraceElement main = stack[stack.length - 1];
String mainClass = main.getClassName ();
```

Comment: I think this would work only if the jar is already executed. But the problem is, that i write a test program, that verifies the correct working of all gui elements in the referenced jar. But the Main Class of the tested jar could be different, so i have to keep this exchangeable.